# After daily log rotation, nothing going to apache error.log and access.log

Tags: server, apache2, log, amazon-ec2

Recently, after some update to Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-57-generic x86_64), I noticed that after the rotation of Apache logs, my execution of:

**sudo tail -n5000 -f /var/log/apache2/error.log**

...would just sit and display nothing.  Looking at error.log and access.log, the file size was 0.  However, if I execute:

**sudo apachectl stop**

**sudo apachectl start**

...THEN the logs would begin collecting data.  The log would then begin:

```
[ssl:warn] [pid 28707:tid 140000050390912] AH01909: ip-nnn-nn-nn-nn.ec2.internal:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[ssl:warn] [pid 28708:tid 140000050390912] AH01909: ip-nnn-nn-nn-nn.ec2.internal:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[mpm_event:notice] [pid 28708:tid 140000050390912] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
 [core:notice] [pid 28708:tid 140000050390912] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

This is running on an AWS EC2 instance (and has worked properly for years).

The Apache server appears to be connected to mod_wsgi properly, even though the logs are collecting no data.

Anyone have any idea what might have happened, and how best to fix it?

Comment: You can specify a post rotation command in `logrotate.conf`. Read `man logrotate.conf`. Use that to restart Apache. Read `man apache2 apachectl` to see if there's z signal you can send to make it restart logging

Comment: There is already a brief logrotate.conf in /etc.  If possible, it would be good to understand WHY logging suddenly stopped.